# Make a post request with File content via Python

Tags: python, file, post, cookies, http-post

i have very large POSt data (over 100 MB) with one cookie, now i want to send it to a server through Python, the POSt request is in a file like this:

```
 a=true&b=random&c=2222&d=pppp
```

This is my following code which only sends Cookies but not the POST content.

```
import requests
import sys
count = len(sys.argv)
if count < 3:
    print 'usage a.py FILE URL LOGFILE'
else:
    url = sys.argv[2]
    data= {'file': open(sys.argv[1], 'rb')}
    cookies = {'session':'testsession'}
    r = requests.get(url, data=data, cookies=cookies)
    f = open(sys.argv[3], 'w')
    f.write(r.text)
    f.close()
```

The code takes File which has POSt data, then the URL to send it , then the OUTPUT file where the response is to be stored.

> Note: I am not trying to upload a file but to send the post content which is inside a file.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should be using `requests.post`. Secondly if you want to post just the data inside the file you need to read the contents of the file and parse it to a `dict` since this is the format that `requests.post` expects data to come in.

Example: (Note: Just showing the relevant parts)

```
import urlparse
import requests
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1], 'rb') as f:
    data = urlparse.parse_qs('&'.join(f.read().splitlines()))

r = requests.post(url, data=data, cookies=cookies)
```